# ms-access EXISTS query to remove rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

i need to remove data from a table. here is what the data looks like (the first two columns):

```
alex hub
liza fds
harry ok
lena yyy
liza ok
```

i need a query that will remove all rows on the following condition: if the second column contains `"ok"` then remove all the rows that contain that name.

so the resulting data set would be:

```
alex hub
lena yyy
```

as you can see all the occurrences of `harry` and `liza` were removed. so far i have the following:

```
delete from table1 where column1 in (
select column1 from table1 where column2='ok')
```

Comment: You may have to use a temporary table to hold the select results - deleting from a table while you're selecting from it rarely works properly and isn't allowed in many databases.

Comment: I don't know that @Marc B's point is correct. It certainly isn't for Access/Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE Exists (
    SELECT t2.column1
    FROM Table1 AS t2
    WHERE
        t2.column2 = "ok"
        And t2.column1 = t1.column1);
```

Comment: @user558922 I don't know why your original approach didn't work.  But I didn't worry about that because your title led me to believe you were looking for an Exists solution.  Someone else may be able to explain why `In (SELECT ...` didn't work with DELETE.  If you got an error message, tell us what it said.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't do:

```
DELETE *
FROM table1
WHERE column2 = 'OK'
```

??

Comment: Because that would leave `liza fds` in the table, and the OP wants to delete all records with a name if there's ANY records where that name has an `ok` value.